# How to read CD audio data in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cd

What is the Microsoft-approved way to extract the raw audio data from an audio CD? I'm hoping to do this with C++ or C.

It's ironic because in XP/Vista/7, there is the IMAPI (Image Mastering API) for *writing* data, but not for *reading* it.

Is there a set of API functions for this? Or do I need to send SCSI commands?

Comment: Stick the CD in the drive and use Explorer to look at it.  Windows mounts it as a file system.

Comment: @Hans: That doesn't provide access to the raw data - just the .cda files - which are meaningless.

Comment: The funny thing is, that the development and beta builds of Windows 95 did not have the .cda bullshit, instead exposing audio tracks as .wav PCM files. Microsoft changed this for the final release after receiving threats from RIAA.

Comment: You can still find the .vxd driver from beta Windows 95 floating on the net. It works on 95, 98 and Me, restoring the "beta 95" behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of code samples...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SimpleAudioCD.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpripper.aspx

Comment: The first link pointed me to what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use open source for this. Have you looked at the [CDEX project](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net/)? The CDRip.dll in this project may be useful.

Comment: I'm kinda looking for a way to access the data *myself* and not through some third party library.

Comment: Still, you can have a look at its code to see how it works internally (http://cdexos.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cdexos/cdex1/trunk/cdexos/CDRip/).

Answer (score 0):

**The** windows audio guy, [Larry Osterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30436/larry-osterman), did a whole [series](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/04/20/playing-audio-cds.aspx) about CD Audio playback on his blog ([DAE](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/05/05/playing-audio-cds-part-10-glitch-free-low-memory.aspx),[MCI](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/04/27/playing-audio-cds-part-6-mci-command-playback.aspx))